# Making a public Monero node with RPC open so I can connect to it from my app

Tags: monerod, rpc

I have the following bitmonero.conf file on my VPS server:

```
no-igd=true

rpc-bind-ip=0.0.0.0
rpc-bind-port=18081
restricted-rpc=true
confirm-external-bind=true

rpc-login=abc:123
```

How do I make it open so I can do RPC calls from my desktop's monero-cli and monero-rpc command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are correctly binding to `0.0.0.0`.

Next you need to make sure your firewall on your server is allowing inbound connections on the port you specified (18081). This step will vary based on what firewall you are using. For example, if you are using `iptables` and `ufw`, you would use the command `sudo ufw allow 18081`. Some VPS providers have a web-based firewall you would need to configure also.

Lastly, you connect to the server using the public IP address your provider assigned to your server.